# Nuxt - server middleware not working on production

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have builded an app using Nuxt and I have created simply server middleware for handling email sending. Everything is working on dev but on production I have 404 error from that endpoint. Does anybody know how to include server-middleware into build files or any other way?

server-middleware:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = require('express')()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
// Some code here
})

module.exports = app
```

Nuxt.config.js

```
serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/contact/send', handler: '~/server-middleware/email.js' }
  ],
```

Response here:
[image]

Comment: Do you use your app as static only or with SSR too ?

Comment: I builded my app with SSR

Comment: Looks fine to me. Didn't you forget any env variable or alike ? I mean, are you sure the issue is coming from here ? Also, are your packages used in the middleware installed as `dependencies` and not just `devDependecies` ?

Comment: Yeah I don't see any string 'contact/send' in build folder :/ I can see that this is no existing in build folder is not builded up :/ I am getting 404 which is correct because it is not there :/

Comment: Where is your app hosted btw? Are you sure it do have a node server for SSR available?

Comment: Yeah, I host on mydevil.net and I know everything is ok, but I got an answer elsewhere 
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9158#issuecomment-820676790

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer on github issue nuxt repo:

> This is correct - server middleware aren't compiled or part of your
> webpack build and so you should make sure to copy them separately into
> production. (As well as making sure that any dependencies they have
> are installed in production.)
>
> (Note that this will change with Nuxt 3 - you'll be able to have a
> single built server that includes your server middleware.)

Issue here:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9158#issuecomment-820676790

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [in-depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72102209/8816585) regarding the whole setup of a serverMiddleware.

---

This solutions seems to work: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1486#issuecomment-325181524

```js
// nuxt.config.js
serverMiddleware: [
  '~/api/index.js',
]
```

```js
// api/index.js
const app = require('express')()
module.exports = { path: '/api', handler: app }

app.get('/say/:word', (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.params)
})
```

Comment: On dev is working but it was working, but on production still I am getting 404 :/

Comment: I wrote some get endpoint "/test"  and after build I don't see any string like "/test" or "test" It is not being builded

Comment: Yep, seems legit that this one is buggy too. Never worked with `serverMiddleware`, it seems a bit tricky.

Comment: Thanks for your time @kissu