# Running an Express server middleware alongside Nuxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, nuxt.js

My endpoints aren't working, and most likely because the server on which express is isn't running correctly. I run my files with `npm run dev` and my express files are in `/middleware`. The endpoint which I'm trying to fetch data from is in a route in `/middleware/routes/crash.js`. In my vue file I have axios preforming a get request to `localhost:3000/api/crash/:id`, however axios returns a 400 error indicating that the file hasn't been found running on the server.

package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nuxt"
}
```

/middleware/index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const crash = require('./routes/crash')
app.use(crash)

module.exports = {
  path: '/middleware',
  handler: app
}
```

/middleware/routes/crash.js:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()
const crypto = require("crypto");
...
router.get('/api/crash/:id')
```

Comment: Is it a 400 error or a 404?

Comment: Do you have a [repro] or a github repo for this one?

Comment: Also, did you pay attention to `Do not add serverMiddleware to the middleware/ directory` in the documentation regarding the link I gave you on your latest question? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#servermiddleware-vs-middleware

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Comment: @kissu Somehow, yes. I'm still having issues with initializing express.js. Absolutely no clue what the cause of it is. I made a new post and a github repo regarding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have at least this in your
`nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  ssr: true,
  target: 'server',
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],
  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api', handler: '~/server-middleware/rest.js' },
  ],
}
```

And a `/server-middleware/rest.js` file with

```js
const app = require('express')()

app.get('/what-is-my-name/:name', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ name: req.params.name, age: 12 })
})

module.exports = app
```

Then, you can use it like this in any `.vue` file

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input id="name" v-model="name" type="text" name="name" />
    <button @click="callNuxtApi">try local Nuxt API</button>
    <div>
      Response from the backend:
      <pre>{{ response }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AccordionList',
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'bob',
      response: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async callNuxtApi() {
      const response = await this.$axios.$get(
        `/api/what-is-my-name/${this.name}`
      )
      this.response = response
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Then, this will successfully work locally (I'm using a dynamic `name` here).

[image]

---

Then, you'll need to deploy it on a VPS, but there is a small gotcha: you will need to deploy your app **and** push the `server-middleware` directory yourself as explained here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9158#issuecomment-820676790

Hence why, platform like Render.com or Heroku are probably not the easiest ones for this kind of task (I'm not even sure that this is possible).

Some homemade VPS or using Nuxt3 would probably be more easily overall IMO.

Comment: This no longer works in latest Nuxt 3

Comment: @malix Nuxt3's approach is indeed quite different. Far more powerful and versatile.