# AWS Amplify redirect middleware NuxtJs requests not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuxt.js, aws-amplify, vue-storefront

I tried to deploy vuestorefront (nuxtjs app) into AWS Amplify according https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/hosting/nuxt/q/platform/js/

My amplify.yml contains:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run generate
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

And I set next data into `redirect & rewrites` section:

```
[
    {
        "source": "/<*>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "404-200",
        "condition": null
    },
    {
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

However, Requests sent to Middlerware generate a "301" with "cancelled" like next example:
[image: Redirect error]

I have a form into `page.vue` with middleware call:

```
import oauthToken from '~/api/getToken';
...
  methods: {
    singIn(e) {
      oauthToken(this.email, this.password);
```

File `~/api/getToken` have an `axios` to call middleware:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const oauthToken = (email, password) => {
  let result;
  axios({
    method: 'GET', url: '/oauth2.js',
    headers: { email, password, },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data.access_token)));
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  return result;
};

export default oauthToken;
```

`/oauth2.js` GET  (in server-middleware/custom-features.js):

```
app.get('/oauth2.js', (req, res) => {
...
      res.status(200).send(response.data);
}
```

Comment: Check the last part of my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72102209/8816585), there is a gotcha regarding the `server-middleware` deployment. It may be related to your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue Storefront requires an active node server, and it's not yet supported to do Lambda deployment yet. We are working on bringing this solution to the framework.