# Create a route with Nuxt2, which is only available on the server side, and which returns JSON

Tags: routes, nuxt.js

I need to create a simple route `/my-route` that returns a JSON `{ "ok": true }`. If possible, this route should be available only from the server.

I found a [documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/server-routes/) but with Nuxt3 only, and Nuxt3 is not released yet.

Anyone knows how to do that with Nuxt 2?

Comment: Nuxt3 is released and already available. For Nuxt2, give a read to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72102209/8816585

Comment: Also, the `this route should be available only from the server` part is basically saying that you want to create an endpoint which is only accessible from another backend? What's the idea with that?

Comment: @kissu No, it means that this route will not be used or even accessible from the rest of the front. No need to serve an HTML with the bundled JS etc. It is just a healthcheck that says to the monitoring system that yes the Nuxt server is alive.

Comment: So, you do have it as SSR? Why not pinging a simple `/healthcheck` page? Either it's served or not.

Comment: @kissu Because `@nuxtjs/i18n` is terribly stubborn and it insists on putting back a language prefix. But I just found a solution. Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: You can always remove the prefix if it is annoying you. Also, I'm pretty sure you can have a route that is not i18n'ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! In `nuxt.config.js`, add a server middleware:

```js
serverMiddleware: [
  {
    path: '/my-route',
    handler: (_req, res) => {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      res.write(JSON.stringify({ ok: true }))
      res.end();
    }
  },
],
```

Comment: Hm, pretty much my initial comment.