# How to run Nuxt2 serverMiddleware with pm2

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, web-deployment, server-side-rendering, pm2

I have a simple Nuxt ssr app with a serverMidlleware handling one api endpoint (`/api/contact`). To deploy the app I am using pm2.
Running the app in development and in production (locally without pm2) everything works fine. Deploying it on a basic ubuntu server using pm2, the api endpoint becomes unreachable (404 not found).

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67136769/8671549), the middleware is not included in the `.nuxt` build. So, I made sure to copy the `api` directory (where my middleware is located) too.

for pm2 deployment, `ecosystem.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'App',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: 'max',
      script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
      args: 'start'
    }
  ]
}
```

and inside `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
serverMiddleware: [
  { path: '/api/contact', handler: '~/api/contact.js' }
]
```

As only the deployment via pm2 fails, I assume the other files are not of interest. I am assuming this must be related to some sort of pm2 config to find the api folder.

Comment: As explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72102209/8816585), you indeed need to copy the whole thing. Not sure what is `apps` doing but couldn't you run a shell command after the deploy of your app? Since you have access to the VPS.

Comment: thanks, copying 'the whole thing' worked, not sure which file I was missing tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72102209/8816585) solved the issue here too.

You probably had something missing in your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  ssr: true,
  target: 'server',
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],
  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api', handler: '~/server-middleware/rest.js' },
  ],
}
```